# Binding parameter not working in Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute an `OdbcCommand` with a binding parameter doing this:

```
OdbcCommand DbCommand = Conn.CreateCommand();
DbCommand.CommandText = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_usrs AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE(in_list(?)));";
OdbcParameter param = new OdbcParameter();
param.Value = Filter.OwnerLogin.ToUpper(); // Working
DbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But for some reason it keeps giving me the `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number` error. If I avoid the binding parameter hardcoding the value like `in_list('" + Filter.OwnerLogin.ToUpper() + "')` works fine, but not otherwise.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My Oracle's a little rusty.. What is this **in_list()** function you appear to be calling? More to the point.. What actually are you hoping to do with this database code? It looks dirty on every level

Comment: @CaiusJard `in_list()` is a function I developed, nothing to worry about. The aim of the query is to create a view so I can do after `WHERE NS.OWNER_LOGIN_ID IN (SELECT * FROM vw_usrs)`, because it's not possible to use `IN` with more than 1000 values, which is what I have.

Answer (score -2):

You must call the list defluxinator on the binding parameter.